# Dynamic combobox list databinding in C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox

Have read a lot this resource and really like it, but now i met problem which i can't neither resolve by myself nor find similar solution.
I'm using C# winforms and linqtosql.
In my userforms I use additional view-class to bind list for comboboxes to let users be able to get and use a name-list of objects while being forbidden to get a whole object itself. (This is not question whether it is a good practice, no matter.)

For example(this is not real code, just for look):
ORM classes:

```
public class Contract
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Contractor Contractor { get; set; }
    public string ContractorID { get; set; }
}
public class Contractor
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

This is additional view-class which is mapping for sqlserver view `Contractor_List` `(SELECT c.ID, c.Name FROM Contractors c)`

```
public class Contractor_List
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

UserForm:

```
public class ContractForm : Form
{
    void Init()
    {
        TextBox nameBox = new TextBox();
        ComboBox contractorBox = new ComboBox();
        BindingSource contractSource = new BindingSource();
        contractSource.DataSource = typeof (Contract);

        nameBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", contractSource, "Name", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation);
        contractorBox.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", contractSource, "ContractorID", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation);


        BindingSource contractorListSource = new BindingSource();
        contractorListSource.DataSource = typeof (Contractor_List);

        contractorBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
        contractorBox.ValueMember = "ID";
    }

}
```

OK. 
My idea is to load contractorBox.DataSource (it’s binding source) when contractorBox.SelectedValue is set.
I found that SelectedValue is not overridable, so I decided to inherit combobox and to create in it a new property called “ID” and do following stuff instead 
In form:

```
contractorBox.DataBindings.Add("ID", contractSource, "ContractorID");
```

In Control (this is real code):

```
    object _id;
    bool _listInitialized;
    public object ID
            {
                get
                {
                    return _id;

                }
                set
                {
                    if (!_listInitialized)
                    {
                        var bindingSource = DataSource as BindingSource;
                        if (bindingSource != null)
                        {
                            var t = (bindingSource.DataSource as Type);
                            var rst = … //Getting List
                            if (rst!=null)
                            {
                                bindingSource.DataSource = rst;
                                _listInitialized = true;
                                SelectedValueChanged += delegate {
                                    if (SelectedValue != ID)
                                    {
                                        ID = SelectedValue;
                                    }
                                };
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _id = value;
                        if (SelectedValue != ID)
                        {
                            SelectedValue = value;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
```

So, this code works fine. I can load form, Contract object and list of contractors and get right contractor name in combobox.
But. I have problem with backing Binding of “ID” property. When contractor in combobox is changed Contract object doesn’t update (neither `ContractorID`, no  `Contractor` Itself) while `ID`, `SelectedValue` and `SelectedItem` of combobox change properly.
Why? What have I do to make this working.

Comment: Please remove the "Update" and post that as your answer and just mark it as the answer.  That's how we like to roll here at SO! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hah. So Simple Solution.

```
public new object SelectedValue
{
    get
    {
        return base.SelectedValue;

    }
    set
    {
        if (!DesignMode)
        {
            if (!_listInitialized)
            {
                var bindingSource = DataSource as BindingSource;
                if (bindingSource != null)
                {
                    var t = (bindingSource.DataSource as Type);
                    var rst = ...///how you get your type list
                    if (rst != null)
                    {
                        bindingSource.DataSource = rst;
                        _listInitialized = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                base.SelectedValue = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

May be will be helpful for someone.